# Salir de un ciclo forEach si se cumple una condición

Tags: javascript

Quiero romper un ciclo forEach en DojoJS, tengo lo siguiente:

```
        array.forEach(oldGraphics.graphics, function (oldGraphic, index) {
            if (JSON.stringify(oldGraphic.geometry.rings) === JSON.stringify(graphic.geometry.rings)) {
                this.myApp.map._layers._draws.remove(graphic);
                oldGraphics.graphics.splice(index, 1);
                oldGraphics = JSON.stringify(oldGraphics);
                localStorage.draws = oldGraphics;

                return false;
            }
            // break;
        });
```

estoy usando Dojo 1.10 (AMD)

Comment: en el siguiente link: [How to short circuit Array.forEach like calling break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break) encontraras la respuesta a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
const hasOldGC = !array.some(oldGraphics.graphics, function(oldGraphic, index) {
  if (JSON.stringify(oldGraphic.geometry.rings) === JSON.stringify(graphic.geometry.rings)) {
    this.myApp.map._layers._draws.remove(graphic);
    oldGraphics.graphics.splice(index, 1);
    oldGraphics = JSON.stringify(oldGraphics);
    localStorage.draws = oldGraphics;

    return true;
  }
});

if (!hasOldGC) {
  // ...
}
```

El método `some` ya no hará más iteraciones si es retornado un valor verdadero. En tu caso, puedes retornar un valor verdadero e inmediatamente negarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Lanzando un BreakException, como en el siguiente fragmento de código

```
var BreakException = {};

try {
  [1, 2, 3].forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el);
    if (el === 2) throw BreakException;
  });
} catch (e) {
  if (e !== BreakException) throw e;
}
```

Fuente: [Misma Pregunta en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch)

```js
try {
 array.forEach(oldGraphics.graphics, function (oldGraphic, index) {
  if (JSON.stringify(oldGraphic.geometry.rings) === JSON.stringify(graphic.geometry.rings)) {
   this.myApp.map._layers._draws.remove(graphic);
   oldGraphics.graphics.splice(index, 1);
   oldGraphics = JSON.stringify(oldGraphics);
   localStorage.draws = oldGraphics;

   return false;
  }
  break;
 });
} catch(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se puede hacer un break; de un foreach por que esta preparado para ejecutarse sin interrupción por lo que puedes convertirlo a un for normal el cual se ejecuta de manera secuencial por lo que si se puede utilizar el break;